# Rails undefined method `model_name' in form partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, routes, partial

I have this model:

```
class ToType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :Name, :TYP_CCM, :TYP_CCM_TAX, :TYP_CDS_ID, :TYP_CTM, :TYP_CYLINDERS, :TYP_DOORS, :TYP_HP_FROM, :TYP_HP_UPTO, :TYP_ID, :TYP_KV_ABS_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_ASR_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_AXLE_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_BODY_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_BRAKE_SYST_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_BRAKE_TYPE_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_CATALYST_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_DRIVE_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_ENGINE_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_FUEL_SUPPLY_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_MODEL_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_STEERING_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_STEERING_SIDE_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_TRANS_DES_ID, :TYP_KV_VOLTAGE_DES_ID, :TYP_KW_FROM, :TYP_KW_UPTO, :TYP_LA_CTM, :TYP_LITRES, :TYP_MAX_WEIGHT, :TYP_MMT_CDS_ID, :TYP_MOD_ID, :TYP_PCON_END, :TYP_PCON_START, :TYP_RT_EXISTS, :TYP_SORT, :TYP_TANK, :TYP_VALVES, :is_in_to
  set_primary_key :TYP_ID
  belongs_to :to_model
  has_many :to_articles, :foreign_key => "to_type_id", :dependent => :destroy
end

class ToArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :details, :manufacturer, :name, :oem_number, :only_with_vin, :quantity, :to_type_id
  belongs_to :to_type, :foreign_key => "TYP_ID"
  belongs_to :to_engine
end
```

(some db is converted from big catalog, so rails conventions are slightly imperfect)

Part of my show view of to_type:

```
%td
            = link_to "Подробнее", admin_catalog_to_to_article_path(c), :class=>'btn btn-primary'
            = link_to "Редактирование", edit_admin_catalog_to_to_type_path(c), :class=>'btn btn-warning'
            = link_to "Удалить", admin_catalog_to_to_type_path(c), :confirm => "!!!Тип #{c.Name} будет удалён!!!! Вы уверены?", :method => :delete, :class => "btn btn-danger"
```

my show action works normally same for my controller:

```
class Admin::Catalog::To::ToTypesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  before_filter :auth_user

  def auth_user
    redirect_to new_admin_session_path unless admin_signed_in?
  end

  def show
    @mod_id = params[:id]
    @man = ToType.find(:all, conditions: {:TYP_MOD_ID => @mod_id}, order: "Name ASC")
    render :layout => 'admin'
  end

  def edit
    @man = ToType.find(params[:id])
    render :layout => 'admin'
  end

  def update
    @man = ToType.find(params[:id])
    if @mod.update_attributes(params[:to_type])
      redirect_to admin_catalog_to_to_type_path(@man.TYP_MOD_ID)
    else
      render :layout => 'admin'
    end
  end

  def new
    @man = ToType.new
    @mod_id = params[:mod_id]
    render :layout => 'admin'
  end

  def create
    @man = ToType.new(params[:to_type])
    @mod_id = params[:mod_id]
    @man.TYP_MOD_ID = @mod_id
    if @man.save
      redirect_to admin_catalog_to_to_type_path(@mod_id)
    else
      render :layout => 'admin'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @man = ToType.find(params[:id])
    if @man.destroy
      redirect_to admin_catalog_to_to_type_path(@man.TYP_MOD_ID)
    else
      render :layout => 'admin'
    end
  end
end

and route:

namespace :admin do
  namespace :catalog do
      namespace :to do
        resources :to_manufacturers, 
                  :to_models, 
                  :to_types, 
                  :to_articles
      end
    end

  end
```

form partial:

```
= form_for [:admin, :catalog, :to, @man] do |f|
  = f.label :id
...
```

When I try edit or create I get:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

I think that something is wrong with connection with model: with update and create. In the log I see that the object is founded in db for edit for example, and in the log I can see that @man is not empty, but I still get `undefined method`model_name' for NilClass:Class` . Why?

**upd**: Full trace

```
        NoMethodError in Admin/catalog/to/to_types#edit

Showing /media/sf__Projects/Denis/app/views/admin/catalog/to/to_types/_edit.html.haml where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: = form_for [:admin, :catalog, :to, @man] do |f|
2:   = f.label :id
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/admin/catalog/to/to_types/edit.html.haml

Rails.root: /media/sf__Projects/Denis

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activemodel (3.2.8) lib/active_model/naming.rb:163:in `model_name_from_record_or_class'
activemodel (3.2.8) lib/active_model/naming.rb:158:in `param_key'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:369:in `form_for'
haml (4.0.3) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:146:in `form_for_with_haml'
haml (4.0.3) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_xss_mods.rb:28:in `form_for_with_haml_xss'
app/views/admin/catalog/to/to_types/_edit.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_admin_catalog_to_to_types__edit_html_haml___4584370517694291299_51970960'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:265:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:238:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
haml (4.0.3) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `block in render_with_haml'
haml (4.0.3) lib/haml/helpers.rb:89:in `non_haml'
haml (4.0.3) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `render_with_haml'
app/views/admin/catalog/to/to_types/edit.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_admin_catalog_to_to_types_edit_html_haml___2140731807560860717_28965400'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/home/pavel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
app/controllers/admin/catalog/to/to_types_controller.rb:18:in `edit'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__3422493215220642812__process_action__1624115620138968240__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2440713806940417433__call__2360308109704352565__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/pavel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/pavel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/pavel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"28752"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

Comment: also i try to rename to to_engines: didn't help... I didnt understand why? (

Comment: The error says that you have nil when you are expecting an object. In the edit code, you don't check to see if the find() returns a record. What happens if you pass in an id that isn't present in the database?

Comment: @Fred but i see that from db it select data

Comment: @Fred so what do you think?

Comment: Given what you have here, the nested resources look strange. I don't understand why you have multiple declarations of the :catalogs namespace under admin (and multiple declarations of :to, and so forth). Perhaps this is confusing rails? Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Fred this was generated by rails g scaffold Admin/Catalog/To/Manufacturer for example: yes it look not so good, but this done rails generators, how and what can i change it?

Comment: @Fred in admin namespace i need to have two more namespaces: catalog and to, all other must be resources: but i don't know how to do so deep nesting, what to write in routes, what in controllers, how to use generators becouse all tutorial in web are very simple, i never saw how to operate with deep nesting

Comment: To change it, simply edit the routes.rb file. Scaffolding is just a starting point. Or rethink the deeply nested namespaces and try a different design; obviously I can't understand the rationale for your design from what little info is here, so I don't know how hard that might be.

Comment: @Fred ok... bad that i can't understand why all models are working but only this one no(

Comment: @Fred also index show views are working normally

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34720/discussion-between-fred-and-brabertaser1992)

Comment: @Fred also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215087/rails-controller-use-other-db-for-destroy-method-update-create-not-working-too

Comment: What do you mean by "I think that something is wrong with connection with model: with update and create"?

Comment: Also, can you please include the exact file names

Comment: @Btuman what do you mean?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that sentence, I also wanted to see the exact file names.

Comment: @Btuman exact file names where ? )) sorry i didn't understand what you want

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35468/discussion-between-btuman-and-brabertaser1992)

Comment: @brabertaser1992 do you know how to use debugger? if yes, put the debugger before form_for and check whether '@man' is present?, what is its value?

Comment: @SachinSingh i almost solve it, some problem with model, if i delete relation of type with model all is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks too easy, but where is `@typ` defined? You have got `@typ` in partial but `@man` in controller.

Comment: sorry, this is other partial... new there is other object, when is one same object i get error.. i eddited question

Comment: so what do you think now?

Comment: Try testing it with `form_for [:admin, :catalog, :to, ToType.new]` and show output.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about namespacing, try: `Admin::Catalog::To::ToType.new` instead of `ToType.new`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ziUn1Zj4   also i try = form_for [:admin, :catalog, :to, Admin::Catalog::To::ToType.new] do |f|

Comment: Expected /media/sf__Projects/Denis/app/models/to_type.rb to define ToType   also why then show works? also i have this model in model folder without any subfolder... ToManu-s and ToModels are same, but there are working, but this no( what a magick( ))

Comment: My last comment was wrong, it would made have too much mess, test going out to the root scope in controller by adding `::` to `ToType.new`  so you will get `::ToType.new`.

Comment: hm( still undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class  maybe teamviewer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35437/discussion-between-brabertaser1992-and-zrl3dx)

Answer (score 1):

You have this in your form `form_for [:admin, :catalog, :to, @typ]`, but you don't have object @typ - you have @man

Comment: sorry, this is other partial... new there is other object, when is one same object i get error.. i eddited question

Comment: and what is fulltrace of error now? you still have @typ in there

Comment: @yes, i updated code, forget about this names(i change in code, forget to update all here), problem is not in that

Comment: see now, i try a little bit with rename, so that was a little bit problem, but you can see that with normall name all is the same

Comment: I got this error when object that was used for form was nil. So check please what is coming to your form - I see controller code, but... And try to make `form_for @man, url: [:admin, :catalog, :to, @man]` - maybe there won't be error

Comment: `- if !@man.nil?
  = @man   `    i see    #<ToType:0x00000005f096f0>

Comment: also  @man, url: [:admin, :catalog, :to, @man]   didn't help(  mistique

Comment: look in here [https://github.com/link-er/check_project](https://github.com/link-er/check_project)

Comment: hm, couldn't start it, my project start normally, but on that say that i must use rails new APP etc, also bundler didn't start

Comment: so, from github seems to work fine... in db it create, just i get No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/catalog/to/to_types", :id=>nil}

Comment: checkout. there were problems with absence fields. but the main thing is that form is working...so maybe you have mistypes somewhere

Comment: hm, i think that form is not working, if i write in partial form_for i see errors, even if i put there only one field)

Comment: hm strange, when i comment in type model as you do, it is working

Comment: heh) what i need was just only belongs_to :to_model, :foreign_key => "TYP_MOD_ID"